# Как сообщить js о том, что появились новые элементы в DOM-е?

Tags: javascript

Привет, знаю что есть точно такой же вопрос но дело в том что пробовал и не работает

```
$('img.star').on('click',function(){
    console.log('hi');
})
```

IMG с  классом  star появляется только тогда когда пользователь добавить изображение, т.е не изначально. Но тем не менее не работает
Если использую такой код работает но при одном клике получается по возрастанию. Т.е кликаю один раз а там показывает что 100, потом 600 крч баг

```
$(document).on('click' ,function(){
$('img.star').on('click',function(){
    console.log('hi');
})
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$(document).on('click', 'img.star' ,function(){
    console.log('hi');
});
```